# Send Magento email on succespage

Tags: email, magento, checkout

By default Magento sends the order confirmation checkout submission, regardless if a payment is finished or not.
Is there a way to have the sending of that mail triggered by the succespage? So after the order is finished, NOT after it is placed.

Greetings,

Marcel

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a really big deal, all you have to do is just override the current event

```
sales_order_place_after
```

and stop sending mails from that event, as magento sends mails from that event. Write your custom event after the payment success and trigger your success/failure e-mail from there.